# Replacing Dallas NVRAM with larger capacity variant?

Tags: batteries, rtc, lithium, sram, backup

[image: DS1225AB Datasheet]

This [DS1225AB-200](https://datasheet.octopart.com/DS1225AB-200IND%2B-Maxim-Integrated-datasheet-12537667.pdf) (8k x 8 = 64kB NVSRAM) is from 1995 and is probably dead (cannot measure from the outside.)  The only close replacement in stock is a [DS1230AB-100](https://datasheet.octopart.com/DS1230AB-100%2B-Dallas-Semiconductor-datasheet-10215111.pdf) (32k x 8 = 256kB.)

- Looking at the two datasheets, the pin-outs are identical except for the inclusion of A13 and A14 on the larger-capacity variant. Can I statically pull these to a rail and have it work?
- Any other caveats to consider?  The timings look similar as well.

Comment: That's why they are NC on the older package. You'll still only get 8K of course, unless you bring them out to switches or port pins...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this worked.

As long as the voltage matches, speed is not *slower* than the original, and any excess address pins are tied to a rail, it will appear to be equivalent.